# Javascript: Function returning last element of array

Tags: javascript

I'm taking Colt Steele's Udemy Course titled: "The Web Developer Bootcamp 2020". I have however become stuck on a certain coding exercise. The exercise objective is as follows: **Please write a function called lastElement which accepts a single array argument. The function should return the last element of the array(without removing the element). If the array is empty, the function should return null.**

I have tried coming up with a solution but cant seem to figure it out. My current best guess is this :

```
function lastElement (num) {
if (num !== undefined){
    return num[num.length -1];
} return null;
```

}

I'm interested in knowing why the function I have written doesn't work and some pointers on how I should rethink the function, so that it does work.

Best Regards Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this condition.

```
if (num && num.length>0)
```

Comment: if(num) checks for all 'falsy' values. Check whether 'num' exists.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this:**

```
function lastElement(arr) {
if(arr.length>0){
   return arr[arr.length-1];
} else{
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function lastElement(test) {
if (test.length == 0)
    return null;
else
    return test[test.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your condition to:

if(num && num.length>0)

additionally, if they decide to enter an argument that is not an array,

if(num && Array.isArray(num) && num.length>0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the difference of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20a%20truthy%20value,type%20coercion%20in%20Boolean%20contexts.) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values:
Empty array is truthy but undefined is falsy, so []!==undefined is true, but:

```
num[num.length -1];
```

means:

```
num[-1];
```

which is undefined .